# Event Log not creted, even with administrative privileges

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, events, logging

I'm using the following code:

```
public static void ErrorRoutine(Exception e, string obj, string method)
{
    //EventLog.Delete("Info3070");  // uncomment this line to delete log
    EventLog log = new EventLog();
    log.Source = "Helpdesk Case1";
    log.Log = "Info3070";

    if (e.InnerException != null)
    {
        log.WriteEntry("Error in Models, object = " + obj + ", method = " + method + ", inner exception = " +
            e.InnerException.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
        throw e.InnerException;
    }
    else
    {
        log.WriteEntry("Error in Models, object = " + obj + ", method = " + method + ", message = " + e.Message,
            EventLogEntryType.Error);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

It is supposed to log errors in an Event Log in the Windows Event Viewer but will not do so even when run as administrator.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. I figured out the problem and embarrassingly was not a problem at all and myself looking in the wrong folder in Event Viewer. You provided some excellent advice on best practices though.

Answer (score 1):

You must define your source first, I suspect "Helpdesk Case1" is not known.

Answer (score 0):

If event log with the specified parameters doesn't exist, you should create it before:

```
const string sSource = "Helpdesk Case1";
const string sLog = "Info3070";

if (!EventLog.SourceExists(sSource))
    EventLog.CreateEventSource(sSource, sLog);

EventLog log = new EventLog { Source = sSource, Log = sLog };
```